# how to receive an emitted event

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

i am using `vue3` with `option api`

as shown below in the code, in the `toggle-1.vue`, i emit `onClsDigitizePolygonInteractionInstanceInit` event.i would like to know how to listen or to receive the emitted event in `toggle-2.vue` please

**toggle-1.vue**:

```
export default {
    emits: {
        'update:vModelToggleDigitize': null,
        onClsDigitizePolygonInteractionInstanceInit: ({ clsDigitizePolygonInteractions }) => {
            if (clsDigitizePolygonInteractions) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        },
    },
    ....
    ....
    ....
    this.$emit('onClsDigitizePolygonInteractionInstanceInit', { clsDigitizePolygonInteractions }) //how the event is emitted
}
```

**toggle-2.vue**:

```
//how to receive emitted event here???
//below is my attempt

<ToggleButtonClearDigitized
    @onClsDigitizePolygonInteractionInstanceInit="onClsDigitizePolygonInteractionInstanceInit">
</ToggleButtonClearDigitized>
....
....
 methods: {
    onClsDigitizePolygonInteractionInstanceInitt(ref) {
        console.log('###ref: ', ref);
    }
},
```

Comment: Are they parent/child components or they are totally unrelated components ?

Comment: @Lk77 would you please provide solutions for both cases?

Comment: sure i made an answer with both cases

Answer (score 0):

If toggle-1.vue is a direct child of toggle-2.vue you can simply listen to the event :

```html
<template>
    <toggle-1 @onClsDigitizePolygonInteractionInstanceInit="onClsDigitizePolygonInteractionInstanceInitHandler">
    </toggle-1>
</template>
```

If they are not parent/child, you can't use $emit,
you will need to rely on an external library like mitt :
https://npm.io/package/mitt

And do :

```js
this.$mitt.emit('onClsDigitizePolygonInteractionInstanceInit', { clsDigitizePolygonInteractions })
```

```js
this.$mitt.on('onClsDigitizePolygonInteractionInstanceInit', this.onClsDigitizePolygonInteractionInstanceInitHandler)
```

Here i'm using $mitt global property that i've setup this way :

```js
import mitt from 'mitt';
app.use({
    install: (app) => {
        app.config.globalProperties.$mitt = mitt();
    }
})
```

Comment: hi, you can say more about real case for shared information with not parent/child relationship

Comment: What do you mean ? what do you want to know more ?